# F# Pattern Match on Seq.Length

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm learning some F# and messing around with pattern matching. I have the below code.

```
Seq.distinct [1; 1; 2] 
   |> match Seq.length with 
      | 1 -> printf "one" 
      | 2 -> printf "two" 
      | _ -> printf "other"
```

But when running or trying to compile it gives the error of:

```
This expression was expected to have type
'a -> int 
but here has type
int
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue is and what exactly is being asked. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do either this:

```
match Seq.distinct [1; 1; 2] |> Seq.length with 
| 1 -> printf "one" 
| 2 -> printf "two" 
| _ -> printf "other"
```

or this:

```
Seq.distinct [1; 1; 2] 
|> Seq.length
|> function
    | 1 -> printf "one" 
    | 2 -> printf "two" 
    | _ -> printf "other"
```

But, as is, you're piping the output from `Seq.distinct` to a `match` expression and not `Seq.length` as you intend.

Comment: Ahhh, now I see what the issue was! Thanks!